# how to use merge fields in custom text tab in docusign api?

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

i am trying to merge  Account object fields in Salesforce with text tabs of Docusign, created using WSDL class using REST api .
However im not able to merge these tabs to my salesforce account field.

```
 "textTabs":[{
    "customTabId": "2",
    "documentId": "1",
    "maxLength": "20",
    "pageNumber": "1",
    "recipientId": "1",


    "templateLocked": false,
    "mergeField": {
    "configurationType":"salesforce",
    "path":"Account.name",
    "writeback":"true",
    "allowSenderToEdit":"true"
    }
   }]
```

i want the recipient to fill the details in the tab and the value to be populated to salesforce fields.
**please help me with the  merge field code**

thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: the mail i send using docusign has some editable text fields ** (linked to Account.Name in salesforce) ** on the template.when the user has signed the mail and entered values in the required text tab .i need the text to be saved into salesforce field(in Account.Name).

Comment: It is case sensitive (Account.Name)

Comment: the problem is that im not able to map the Input values given to the text tab in any object of salesforce ,not even to Docusign Status Sobject.Help me with the mapping part please